# Hide Row Group header if child group has no rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following Row Groups structure:

[image]

And then under each UnterlagGruppe there is an UnterlagProduct product row. Sometimes, products are not shown but their UnterlagGruppe group name is still shown, like this:

[image]

As you can see, there are some products that belong to UnterlagGruppe group "Regal 1". They are hidden, but their group header name is still visible. How do I hide the group header name row if there are no children rows in that row group?

I tried this condition for 'hidden' in row visibility:

```
=IIf(CountRows("UnterlagGruppe") = 0, True, False)
```

But the group header name rows are still visible.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying that the rows that exist for "Regal 1" are hidden with some expression in the `Hidden` property?  If so, you should be using the same expression to hide the header row.

Comment: @Steve-o169 yes, that's what it boiled down to after I did some more research after posting the question. Thanks!